# Why would System Notifications report updates available but each of sudo apt-get update, software updater and muon updater do not find updates?

Tags: 14.04, updates, kde, update-manager, notification

I have this same scenario on 2 separate machines
The plasma desktop frequently shows notifications like this:

```
 An update is available for your system. There are 3 updated packages.
```

However, when I do any of the following 3 items, no updates are found

1. at the terminal: `sudo apt-get update`
2. run Software Updater
3. run Muon Update Manager

I am running 14.04 LTS, with KDE.

I have tried `sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
which is mentioned in several of the posts which come up from this question, and have read many trying to find out how this could happen.

Somewhere the different tools, notification manager, and updaters must be using different lists against which they check for available updates.

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` would be the command to try.

Comment: I've noticed similar behavior where the Software Updater says I'm up to date, but "sudo apt-get upgrade" finds additional updates to install.

Comment: Changing "update" to "upgrade" is not the answer. I have been routinely running both commands, and running the 2 update managers, after I get notifications of pending updates. All the commands do nothing, but the notification manager still says there is a change to apply.

Comment: This issue still persists, one thing I have noticed is that I have 2 running the std plasma desktop, and 2 running KDE, and this only happens with KDE.